# Encryption in Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle, encryption

Recently I am trying to expand my knowledge about communication between databases in Oracle and I would like to get answer for few questions:

#### *Problem*

I am sending query through one database to another via LINK, for instance:

```
insert into testme@linkme values (1, ‘Hello World’);
```

where testme is destination table in second database and linkme is my link.

#### *Questions*

1. When sending query, are my data vulnerable (are they encrypted somehow during this process)?
2. If yes, could you briefly tell me more?
3. If no, is there any way to make this process safe?
4. Also, do you know any tools that I could use to test what happens with my data during sending process?

Comment: If you really want to see what is transmitted, you want a packet sniffer.  Oracle relies on standard network protocols.  Oracle can encrypt what it submits to the network. but it is a big subject.  I'd suggest you look at the Database Advanced Security Administrator's Guide. There is a chapter on Configuring Network Data Encryption

Comment: Thank you @EdStevens. I'll check the Database Advanced Security Administrator's Guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY          "PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG" 
as
  FUNCTION decrypt_val( p_val IN RAW ) RETURN VARCHAR2  
  IS
    l_decrypted RAW(32);
    l_decrypted_string VARCHAR2(32);
    L_USER  varchar2(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY raw(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
        L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                            ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                              DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
        L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                        + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

        l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
                ( SRC => P_VAL,
                  TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                  key => L_KEY );

        l_decrypted_string := utl_i18n.raw_to_char
                    ( data => l_decrypted ,
                      src_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );
        RETURN l_decrypted_string;

  end DECRYPT_VAL;

  FUNCTION encrypt_val( p_val IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  is
    L_VAL RAW(32);
    L_ENCRYPTED raw(32);
    L_CHARACTER_SET varchar2(10);
    L_STRING varchar2(32);
    L_KEY RAW(250);
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE PLS_INTEGER;
  begin


    L_KEY := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW
                        ( data => '98345678901234567890123456789012',
                          DST_CHARSET => 'AL32UTF8' );
    L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE := dbms_crypto.encrypt_aes256 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC 
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
    L_VAL := utl_i18n.string_to_raw
              ( data => p_val,
                dst_charset => 'AL32UTF8' );

    L_ENCRYPTED := dbms_crypto.encrypt
                   ( SRC => L_VAL,
                     TYP => L_ENCRYPTION_TYPE,
                     key => L_KEY );


    return L_ENCRYPTED;
  EXCEPTION when OTHERS then
    RETURN SQLCODE||'-'||SQLERRM;
  end ENCRYPT_VAL;
end PKG_LOGI_PWD_REG;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you explain how this code solves the problem?